# How to update Array value in Service using Input from child component?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components, eventemitter, html-input

I am trying to update the value of an Array in my service from child component.

Here is the service at the top level of application

feature.service.ts

```
export class FeatureService {
    
  private myFeatures: MyFeature[] = [
    new Feature(1, '1st Empty String'),
    new Feature(2, '2nd Empty String'),
    new Feature(3, '3rd Empty String'),
  ];
        
  getFeatures() {
    return this.myFeatures.slice();
  }
}

printFeatureArray() {
  console.log(this.myFeatures); 
}
```

As you can see it, it initialises MyFeatures Array to hold the most up date version of my data,

I would like to change this data through a child component, and be able to call the printFeatureArray function to print the updated values.

Here are the child components constructing my feature items from the getDocFeatures function generating a reference for display, this component is used to create individual items per instance.

component.ts

```
export class Component {
  myFeatures: MyFeature[] | undefined;
        
  constructor(private docBuilderService: DocBuilderService) {}
    
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myFeatures = this.FeatureService.getDocFeatures();
  }
}
```

component.html

```html
<div
  class="list"
  *ngFor="let myFeature of myFeatures; let i = index"
>
          
<app-my-item [docFeature]="docFeature"></app-my-item>
</div>
```

Finally from within the my-item component I have an input HTML element that I would like to record user input and populate the myFeatures Array on the very top level.

```html
<input
  #inputTag
  (keyup)="getValue(inputTag.value)"
  [ngClass]="addClassTemplate()"
  (click)="onSelected()"
  type="text"
  placeholder="{{ docFeature?.inputValue }}"
/>
```

my-item.component.ts

```
export class MyItemComponent {
  value: string | undefined;
        
  constructor() {}
          
  getValue(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

How do i update the original Array inside the service from the bottom level of this component tree?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a Subject and a Subscription. Then you can subscribe to it. If you change anything all subscribed components gets informed.

Comment: The component to the Service. And the service call the Subjects "next" method to push a new value. Look for Angular Service Subject. I think you wanna find many. If not let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Service

For a cross communication a Subject in a Service is the best practice.

*myService*

```
private mySubject: Subject<string> = new Subject();

getMySubject() {
  return this.mySubject.asObservable();
}

doSomething(text: string) {
  this.mySubject.next(text);
}
```

### Component

**Code Behind**

```
...
private mySub!: Subscription;
myTextData: string = "";

constuctor(private myService: MyService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.mySub = this.myService.getMySubject().subscribe(data => { this.myTextData = data; }
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.mySub.unsubscribe();
}
```

**Components HTML**

```
<div>
  {{ myTextData }}
</div>
```

You can use an `array` of objects, too. And then use it with `*ngFor`. All the same. Every time the service calls the Subjects `next` method, all components they subscribe to it will be updated.

**Important** We have the `mySub` object which we `unsubscribe` on `ngOnDestroy` this is very important! Otherwise the subscription is multiplied and fires multiple times. Thats not what we want :-).
**Second Important** In the Service we'll never return the `Subject` directly. Instead we return its Observable. Looks a little strange but that is the correctly way to do this and not a workaround.

All about this [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables).